# Cordova 3 In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

How can I install / migrate In-App Purchase Manager to Cordova 3 (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager)?

Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fork that addresses Cordova 3:

https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS

And article on its usage:
http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-app-purchase-on-ios/